# I need to remove all of the plagarized parts to my thesis

Tags: phd, thesis, plagiarism

I am writing my thesis. How do I get rid of plagiarized parts? How do I make sure that all my references are correct?

Comment: To get rid of plagiarist parts: Delete thesis and start over, writing everything yourself this time.

Comment: The easiest way is to not plagiarize at all to begin with. Every sentence that goes into the draft thesis should either be your own words or in quote marks, with a reference. Every idea should either be your own idea, or referenced.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "plagiarist parts". Are you saying you plagiarized parts of your thesis (in which case, rewrite them from scratch) or are you just asking for ways to avoid plagiarism as you write new material?

Comment: +1. If there is Best Question of 2015 nomination, this will be in my top 5.

Comment: Is it really "unclear what you're asking"? I mean, it is a superbly awkward question, but I don't find it particularly unclear.

Comment: What's unclear to me is what type of "plagiarism" are we talking about? Did the OP use someone else's *words*, with a citation but not in quotes? (Easy to fix) Or use someone else's *words* without a citation or quotes? (Have to figure out where you've done it, then find a citation and add quotes or rephrase.) Or use someone else's ideas without a citation? (Surely you'd be able to remember which ideas and then find the reference.) Did the OP really plagiarise, or is he/she just confused about what is legit? Is the OP just trying to get past Turnitin?

Comment: @xLeitix I agree that the question is clear. However, "superbly awkward" barely scratches the surface of how un-grokkable it is that the question even exists. It's kind of like sitting there, repeatedly poking yourself in the ribs, and then asking The Internet why your ribs feel funny.

Comment: Why is this closed as "unclear"?

Answer (score 16):

If you think/know that parts of your thesis are plagiates you and/or your supervisors seem to have failed. You'll have to do as Tobias Kildetoft suggests in the comments, and rewrite those parts from scratch in your own words.

To check if your references are correct: read them.