# What is the effect on a supervisor if a graduate student has been found to have plagiarised?

Tags: advisor, plagiarism, reputation

In a well voted [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/who-is-responsible-for-detecting-plagiarism-in-a-phd-thesis/38573#comment2231_1482) in a question about responsibility to detect plagiarism it notes that it rests with the author. This well voted [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/46136/12454) on a now on-hold question about removing plagiarized parts of a thesis states the following which could read to imply some responsibility for the supervisor.

> If you think/know that parts of your thesis are plagiates you and/or your supervisors seem to have failed.

Regardless of the above in regard to responsibility of detecting plagiarism if a student does plagiarise, I assume it must have some impact on the supervisor.

Has there been any cases that have shown what is the effect on a supervisor (career wise/reputation etc.) if a graduate student has been found to have plagiarised?

Comment: [This is what the effect looks like,](http://mungowitzend.blogspot.in/2015/05/hitler-finds-out-grad-student-coauthor.html)

Answer (score 1):

When reading "the effect on a supervisor", the first case coming to my mind is that of [Haruko Obokata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruko_Obokata), whose supervisor had to commit suicide for her misconduct. But this is not plagiarism.

It is hard to define precisely the affect on reputation. There is a case, where a PhD student, then post doc in the same group, plagiarized 11 papers. His supervisor was the co-author in all 11 papers, but it seemed not to affect his career. I'm not sure about his reputation.

Here are the details of the case: http://carl.cs.indiana.edu/6S/plagiarism/

Comment: Obokata's supervisor didn't have to commit suicide, in fact many Japanese were surprised he did (while others wondered if there was something between him and Obokata that would have caused such an emotional response).